# Intellij IDEA MySQL cannot create table

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am unable to create a table even though all Intellij IDEA settings are correct. There is no problem with the database connection. But I can't create the table. How can I create a table on MySQL using Java Spring Boot?

Entities:

```
package entities;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "employees")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email_id")
    private String emailId;
}
```

Application Properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3300/employee_management_system
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Pom XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.works</groupId>
    <artifactId>EmployeeManagementSystem</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>EmployeeManagementSystem</name>
    <description>EmployeeManagementSystem</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Test Connection:

[test connection screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCxUR.png)

[database screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnL5u.png)

Comment: Try to change ddl-auto to `create` and check. If it doesn't work, add error stack trace to the question

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There isn't error but employees table can not create. My code works. Test connection works. But table can not create.

Comment: All the other tables get created? Or is this the only table

Comment: Do you want to create `employee_management_system` in `employee_management_system schema`? If not change the name of table in Employee entity. But I don't think that's an issue. Do you have explicit datasource declaration?

Comment: I have one table which name is employee_management_system. No table is created under the table. I added a new screenshot to the question. @YJR

Comment: As  @ShivajiPote mentioned  try another name such as employee instead
employee_management_system

Comment: I tried like this. But it can not work. I edited and added it above. @YJR

Comment: Maybe search for similar questions: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+stackoverflow.com+spring+boot+not+creating+tables

Comment: I searched and I tried the solutions. But there isn't solution for my project. @O.Jones

Comment: @MehmetAliKarabulut Can you share minimum reproducible example? Upload example to GitHub/GitLab

Comment: GitHub link is here for this project : github.com/mehmetalikarabulut/employee_management_system @ShivajiPote